# if on Mac, how to see the Device Manager?

Tags: macos, device-manager

When I reading a document on the Internet:

> go into the properties of your serial-to-USB adapter in Device Manager.  It will tell you right there which port it is using.

if on Mac, how to see the Device Manager?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Mac doesn't have a device manager, because mainly devices manage themselves; they almost never need fiddling with or new drivers adding.

The closest equivalent is the System Report, accessed from
 menu > About this Mac > System Report...

[image]

If any device has adjustable parameters, they will be in a Prefs Pane instead, in System Preferences.

Comment: ...and the hardware configurations are all quite standard, Apple being the sole manufacturer. You don't have random compositions of devices dynamically competing for IRQ lines and port addresses as with PCs, so even less need for a "Device Manager".

Comment: With that said. The Device Manager serves other purposes than just installing drivers for third-party hardware. For example, disabling a Device not needed or not working anymore (which can happen on a mac too). Apple just has a bunch of excuses why stuff (useful tools) is not present - because it's not needed... well if not needed why are people asking for it... I'm just wondering... Controlling the mac by keyboard also seems to be a thing not needed... Well, I'd actually love it.

Comment: If you have a new question why not ask it? You'd have to drop the rant aspect unless you want heavy down-votes [the golden rule, don't irritate those you are asking help of], but asking about keyboard control or disabling devices would be perfectly valid - & indeed have answers. If not on here, then maybe at [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: "because mainly devices manage themselves" - complete nonsense. It does not have it because the UNIX kernel is monolythic and non-adjustable.